# Flickering light (on click) animation in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML5 comic book for iPad only that I am making interactive.  On Page 8 of the comic book (see link below), the scene I am referring to is in the bottom right and should appear dark because there is currently a  with a dark version of what is underneath it, to make it look as though light has not been switched on.

[Link to the comic](http://www.spiritdigital.co.uk/outpost/issue-interactive/08.html)

Here's what I want to happen:

1. On click, a sound plays (perfect)
2. On click, the opacity of the dark background  layer flickers on and off in sync with the short electricity sound effect heard at the beginning of the sound that plays.  The opacity should end at 0, to show that the light is now on.

Here's what currently happens:

1. On click, a sound plays (perfect)
2. On click, the opacity of the dark background  layer sets to 0 but it returns to 1 once the user releases the click.

Basically, I to introduce a delay to the opacity and a 'flicker' between the opacity parameters to imitate a flickering light.

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="if(!playing) document.getElementById('player').play(); else document.getElementById('player').pause();">

    <div class="ibox" id="p8s5">

        <div id="flicker"></div>    

        <button id="playButt" class="animated flash" onclick="if(!playing) document.getElementById('player').play(); else document.getElementById('player').pause();">                
        </button>

    </div> 

</a>
```

CSS

```
div#flicker {
opacity: 1;
-transition-property: opacity;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
position: absolute;
bottom: 1px; right: 1px;
width: 245px; height: 341px;
background: url('img/p8s5.jpg') no-repeat;
}

div#flicker:active, div#flicker:focus {
  opacity:0;
}
```

Hope you can help.

Many thanks,
Matt

Comment: What code are you currently using, please post it here rather than us having to look at the source.

Comment: Apologies, I have added the code now.

Comment: Where would the flickering come from your code? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Well, there is nothing there to make it flicker yet.  I imagined that the flickering would be a CSS3 transition between opacity 1 and 0. I may be wrong but I think it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mGqma/) may solve your problem.

First of all, it creates an animation with css3:

```
.animateFlicker {
    -webkit-animation: flicker 17s;    
}

@-webkit-keyframes flicker{
    0% {opacity:1}
    3% {opacity:0}
    6% {opacity:0}
    7% {opacity:1}
    8% {opacity:0}
    9% {opacity:1}
    10% {opacity:0}
    99% {opacity:0}
    100% {opacity:1}
}
```

And then it listens to the click event with jQuery to execute the animation and stop it after the time is over.

```
$('#flicker').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('animateFlicker');
    setTimeout(function() 
    {
        $this.removeClass('animateFlicker');
    }, 17000);    
});​
```

Note I have only used webkit, so you will need to change it to make it work properly in all browsers.

Comment: Thank you so much, admenva.  I knew that it was possible but I wasn't sure how.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Going to have a good old play with this later.

Comment: I still can't get it to work.  I have put the code in exactly as you said but the animation is still not being triggered.  Could it be something to do with the selector I am using in the JS?

http://www.spiritdigital.co.uk/outpost/issue-interactive/08.html

Comment: Also, when I click the first interactive div element to trigger the drop down image, it pushes the flicker div down too. Very annoying, any ideas?

Comment: Definitely, I think the first issue will be resolved when you paste the jQuery code in any of your files. For the second thing, I guess it's a problem of the jQuery in your audio.js file, in which you are changing the `background-position` property. (In any case I haven't been able to test it so that's just a guess).

Comment: The jQuery code was in 'script.js' in the root directory, but now I have put it in the document's <head> so you can see it.  It is worth noting that, if I add the 'animateFlicker' class directly to #flicker, then the animation is triggered on page load.  For some reason though, that class is not being added when the #flicker div is clicked.

http://www.spiritdigital.co.uk/outpost/issue-interactive/08.html

I have solved the second issue, it was because of a dummy span tag required for the audio player.

Comment: You should paste it at the end of the document (just before closing the `<body>` tag). This is because you are trying to execute the jQuery code before loading the page, and therefore nothing happens as nothing has been loaded yet. Other solution would be to wrap the code with `$(document).ready(function () {...});`. Please change it and hope it works!

Comment: Oh wow, it was that simple.  It's working now I put the script at the end of the document.  Does this apply for things like the jQuery library?  Is it generally the safe way to load scripts at the end?

Comment: It doesn't apply for the jQuery library as it doesn't execute any code. However, it is preferable to load all your javascript at the end of the page for performance reasons (Unless you're using an external source for the jQuery library such as [Google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)).